# C# Process trying to execute 'move' command

Tags: c#, cmd, process

I am trying to execute 'move' command, how you would in the command prompt, but it fails using Process.Start(). I understand move seems to be some integrated part of cmd and not an isolated executable, is there any way to trigger it using Process anyway ? I need to move some special location folder and trying to use elevated process instead of Directory.Move.

Comment: `cmd /C <stuff>`? I.e. invoke `cmd.exe`, and tell it to run its `move` command

Comment: Is elevation not available to your app so you can do it via C#?

Comment: I tried invoking cmd and tell it to run move but it does not work

Comment: its a net core service which tries to migrate some data, it can run process in elevated mode but it fails to Directory.Move

Comment: Does Directory.Move fails with UnauthorizedAccessException?

Comment: @frno What exactly did you try, and what makes you think it doesn't work? I've definitely called into `cmd` to do similar things in the past

Answer (score 1):

That should work. The arguments should start with '/C' otherwise won't work.

```
var process = new Process
    {
         StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = @"/C move ""test.txt"" ""test/test.txt""",
                UseShellExecute = false
            }
    };

process.Start();
```

Comment: (Just as a note: the default for `UseShellExecute` changed from `true` to `false` with the introduction of .NET Core. Annoyingly, therefore, portable code which runs on both Framework and Core needs to always explicitly set it, as this answer does)